# SQL Server 2008 - give user access to certain tables and views only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions, roles

I need to allow certain user access to only specific views and tables. I have tried following so far

- Created a user ex_user
- Created a role rviewonly

  ```
  deny view definition to rviewonly;
  ```

Then I executed this sql

```
GRANT SELECT ON vwBI_PEOPLE TO rviewonly
```

It seems to work, and this ex_user can do a select command on it however I do not see this `vwBI_PEOPLE` in list of views in Management Studio. There are about 50 views that I have to give this user access to along with about 40 different tables - I want the user to be able to see the available views and tables in Management Studio's Object Explorer

Comment: In my answer, I'm assuming that you added the user to the role, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have denied `view definition` at the database level (no object specified) to the role/user, this trumps any `grant view definition on ...` that you may make on an individual object. `Grant select on ...` will also allow view definition on that object without having to specify `grant view definition`.

I recommend revoking [view definition](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175808%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) at the database level:

```
revoke view definition to rviewonly;
```

And simply let your `grant select on` statements do the work for you. You shouldn't have to rerun them again after running the above revoke. `view definiton` by itself would be good for giving a user/role access to metadata, but not data.

Note that any `deny` will always trump a `grant` including the cases where you deny a role access but grant the user access or vice-versa.

I just verified this on a SQL Server 2008 R2 dev box. I'm not sure if any settings exist that might alter this behavior for your instance.

Comment: Thanks for this - and so how do I allow access to tables? second question: how do i hide all the "system views" from the user?

Comment: @user18620 Do you have any permissions granted or denied to the [public role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659(v=sql.100).aspx)?

Comment: I didn't touch the public role so I guess it is by default assigned. Do I need to remove the public role from the user or from the database?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question before.  I, instead of using a role, just granted select on the user itself.  This is something handy for multiple table permission granting:

```
SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON '+name+' TO ex_user;'
from sysobjects
where name in (

'[Enter table]',
'[names here]',
'[in a list]',
'[to grant permissions]'

)
```

Then copy all the results, throw it in a query, and run it.  Especially handy if all the tables you want to grant access to are prefixed with the same grouping of letters.

Example: You can just change the above query's where clause to be `where name like 'TST_%'`, if all the tables/views you're granting start with "TST_".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ex_user to rviewonly role [sp_addrolemember](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx):

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember rviewonly, [ex_user];
```

Then use revoke instead of deny view definition to the role:

```
revoke view definition to rviewonly;
```